# Prove the following measure statement

Tags: measure-theory

**Prove:** An algebra $A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra if and only if it is close for disjoint numerable unions.

Well my doubt is in the right direction because I don't know how to start, the left direction is okay.

After thinking about it I did the following development:

1. I write $\bigsqcup_{j=1}^{\infty} A_j$ = $(\cap^{\infty}A_j^{c})^c$
2. Using the properties of being a $\sigma$-algebra, I write that $A_j \in A$ so $A_j^{c} \in A$ so $\cap^{\infty}A_j^{c} \in A$ and finally $(\cap^{\infty}A_j^{c})^c \in A$.
3. And like $\sqcup^{\infty} A_j$ = $(\cap^{\infty}A_j^{c})^c$ then $\sqcup^{\infty} A_j \in A$.

I don't know if it is correct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A_1,A_2,\dots$ be elements of the algebra.

Then for every $n$ the set $B_n=A_n\setminus\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}A_k\right)$ is also an element of the algebra and the sets $B_1,B_2,\dots$ are disjoint.

Since in your case the algebra is closed under disjoint countable unions we can conclude that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n$ is an element of the algebra.

But: $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n$$ so actually we proved that the algebra is closed under countable unions.

Further by its nature the algebra is closed under complementation.

Our final conclusion is that we are dealing with a $\sigma$-algebra.